# params key inaccesible - I lose parameters content from form to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't get it, I think it's a silly / stupid issue but I can't figure out why. I have form returning 2 parameters but I just can't retrieve them !

I just can't figure out what's wrong !

```
<%= form_for @template do |t|  %>
  <%= t.label :description, "Description" %><br>
  <%= t.text_field :description %>
  <%= t.trix_editor :text %>
  <%= t.submit 'Enregistrer', class: 'Btn' %>
<% end %>
```

so, after in console:

```
>> params

=> <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"J0pCf1KluTo2uXnpmD9uBFi6bE7FtxI2Cp1gB1KAOFhsR8Sli2lN2vQuXOv/I816vHBT+BYvNb5D7eOdv4CQCQ==", "template"=><ActionController::Parameters {"description"=>"ds", "text"=>"<div>ds s</div>"} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Enregistrer", "controller"=>"templates", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"2"} permitted: false>

>> params.has_key?(:text)
=> false

>> params.require(:template).permit(:description, :text)

=> <ActionController::Parameters {"description"=>"ds", "text"=>"<div>ds s</div>"} permitted: true>

>> params.has_key?(:text)
=> false
```

Any help will be appeciated !

greg

Comment: it's the same for description by the way :-(

Comment: I believe you have to use `params[:template].has_key?(:text)`

Comment: you are right Anees, it's the "access path"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the "root" of the params you're sending, in this case and due to the way you're using form_for it's `template`.

If you do `params[:template]` you'll get what's inside:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"description"=>"ds", "text"=>"<div>ds s</div>"} permitted: false>
```

There's is the key `text` you're looking for.

So you can just use [`Hash#key?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-key-3F):

```
params[:template].key?(:text)   # true
params[:template][:text]        # "<div>dss</div>"
params[:template][:description] # "ds"
```

Comment: it's working, you are right, thanks for your answer !
I just don't understand that this time I have to access the params this way while not for other forms, I will dig a little bet to understand what is my mistake / missunderstanging